# Cisco ASA: What is the best way to restrict access of nodes in the same network to each other?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

There is a network with five nodes on one interface. These nodes should not be accessible to each other. An option is to use an ACL, but is there another way?

Comment: "_these are virtual hosts on server._" That, unfortunately, is off-topic here. You could try to ask about that on [sf] for your business network. Hosts on the same network do not send traffic to a router or firewall where the ACL could be applied, they send traffic directly to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the hosts are in the same VLAN and the switch they are connected to support it, there's a feature made precisely for this case: [private vlan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN)

This allow the devices to communicate with remote networks but not with each other.

As explained in the linked article `private VLAN` is the name of the feature in Cisco world. Some other vendors have the same feature with another name, mainly `port isolation`

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, I know about Privat VLAN, but these are virtual hosts on server. And I don't have access to it. I think the support group for these VMs is not going to configure the Privat VLAN on its own and asks the NOC for this.=))

Comment: The ASA is a gateway, communication between hosts in the same layer 2 network doesn't go to the gateway, but is done directly between host, so you can only act on the hosts or the (virtual) switch. If the team that manage the switch is not cooperative, we cannot help you much.